# Timestamped values

Tags: haskell, newtype

I wanted a type for timestamped values that had an appropriate `Semigroup` instance (latest value wins). It turns out that `Max (Arg UTCTime a)` does exactly what I want, but is really awkward to work with directly so I wrote this:

```
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Thyme ()
import Data.Thyme.Clock

newtype Stamped a =
  Stamped' (Max (Arg UTCTime a))
  deriving (Show, Eq, Semigroup, Functor)
  -- Many other useful classes could be added here

pattern Stamped :: UTCTime -> a -> Stamped a
pattern Stamped s v = Stamped' (Max (Arg s v))

unstamp :: Max (Arg a b) -> b
unstamp (Max (Arg _ v)) = v

stamp :: IO a -> IO (Stamped a)
stamp a = do
  ts <- getCurrentTime
  result <- a
  pure (Stamped ts result)
```

And some other helpers:

```
updateStamped :: TVar (Stamped a) -> Stamped a -> STM ()
updateStamped v n = modifyTVar v (<> n)

updateStamped' :: TVar (Stamped a) -> Stamped a -> STM ()
updateStamped' v n = modifyTVar' v (<> n)
```

Is there a better way to do this? I haven't seen pattern synonyms used with a newtype like this so I feel like I missed something more idiomatic.

Comment: Instead of pattern synonyms, you could just use a normal data type, i.e. `data Stamped a = Stamped UTCTime a` and write your `Monoid` by hand.